# Django - Error: No module named x - When trying to reuse apps

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I have version 1.3.1 installed.

I have created two projects: **projectone** and **projecttwo** using django-admin.py

And in **projectone** I have an app called **blog** created using python manage.py startapp

In **projecttwo** setings.py file when put the following in installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (  
    other code goes here...
    'projectone.blog'
)
```

And then when I run projecttwo using manage.py I get:

```
Error: No module named projectone.blog
```

I have __ init __.py files placed correctly.

I just cannot figure out why. Maybe because projectone is not in pythonpath? Is that what django-admin.py does? and not doing it on mine for some reason? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what manage.py does:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-py-and-manage-py

It dynamically adds your apps to the python path when you use it - i.e. when you are using **runserver** during development.

You have two separate projects so when you run either one you will only have the apps from that particular project on the python path. To use an app from one project 'outside', you need to manually add these apps to your global python path if you want to use them outside of the current project

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a **Project** in your INSTALLED_APPS on settings.py, those are different projects. Instead you need to create just one project and create differents apps.

Remember that apps are meant to be reusable so if you need the blog app in other project just reuse it.

If you are new to Django you should read the Tutorial in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/)